# Getting message "DEBUG -- : Connection failed: Connection is not open" with Turntabler

Tags: ruby

I'm using [Turntabler](https://github.com/obrie/turntabler/), a Ruby gem for interacting with turntable.fm. I created this simple "Hello World" program:

```
require 'turntabler'
require_relative 'config.rb'

config = KevbotConfiguration.load_config # Reads a YAML file

Turntabler.run(config[:email], config[:password], :room => config[:room], :reconnect => true, :reconnect_wait => 30) do
  on :user_spoke do |message|
    # Respond to "/hello" command
    if (message.content =~ /^\/hello$/)
      room.say("Hey! How are you @#{message.sender.name}?")
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this program, it fails with this message:

```
$ ruby src/main.rb 
D, [2013-11-09T15:57:17.602019 #10407] DEBUG -- : Connection failed: Connection is not open
D, [2013-11-09T15:57:47.634282 #10407] DEBUG -- : Attempting to reconnect
D, [2013-11-09T15:57:47.719336 #10407] DEBUG -- : Connection failed: Connection is not open
D, [2013-11-09T15:58:17.744107 #10407] DEBUG -- : Attempting to reconnect
D, [2013-11-09T15:58:17.828378 #10407] DEBUG -- : Connection failed: Connection is not open
D, [2013-11-09T15:58:47.854309 #10407] DEBUG -- : Attempting to reconnect
# etc.
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

---

**EDIT:** This is the contents of `config.rb`:

```
module KevbotConfiguration
    require 'yaml'

    def self.load_config
        return YAML.load_file('config.yaml')
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm reading the value of the `config` hash straight from YAML, I have to use strings to access the hash values instead of symbols:

`Turntabler.run(config['email'], config['password'], :room => config['room'] #...`

---

More generally, what was happening was that my e-mail, password, and room weren't being passed to `Turntabler.run` correctly. In my case, accessing the hash elements the wrong way resulted in passing `nil` for the three arguments.